How to visualize geometry optimization using VESTA?
Using XCrySDen, I can generate animation in GIF/MP4 format from the Quantum ESPRESSO relaxation calculation output (as shown below). I know it is also possible through ASE to visualize the BFGS optimization. However, I am interested if this can be done using VESTA since images produced by VESTA seems to have more publishing quality. In the following image, the relaxation of an isolated dopant is shown with the green arrow being the force on the atom. Visualization of the force is not a must, only the displacements of the atomic positions are enough.
Can it be done using VESTA from QE output file, and if yes, how? I am open to ideas of parsing the data from the QE output file and then making it "VESTA friendly", if it is possible to animate this type of geometric optimization using VESTA.


I am yet to figure this problem out with Vesta - however if you just want something other than Xcrysden, Jmol can write animations directly via scripts (it is a bit fiddly).

To substantiate the comment by @RobertLawrence, see e.g. installment 6 of 18 Script Console and Script Commands in IIT Bombay's spoken tutorials (the specific landing page including data, script & video (mirrored on youtube) as a starter. For the commands available, see Jmol's compiled list in general, and its wiki page about animations in particular.
